# Raised colon ligature in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, roboto

Is there a way to enable your app to use raised colons between numbers for a font in Android? I believe the Roboto font supports it based on the lock screen which shows the colon vertically centered, as opposed to some other apps.

Here's an example of what I mean, the top one is what the Roboto font looks like by default (the colon is too low) and the bottom one is what it looks like on the lock screen:

[image: centered colon]

Answer (score 0):

Try unicode glyph U+02F8 -- hopefully the font supports it.

Comment: I tried it, it's the one on the right (the one on the left is U+A789 and seems to be centered, but unfortunately the dots are square): http://i.imgur.com/OlTn4zw.png

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the other comment I found one that works (the one mentioned is too high for me)

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+A789

Simply copy&paste this character ꞉

Example: `8꞉93`

At least my Pixel 3a displays that one correctly centered